# Mono uses just one core on the server

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage, mono

I have a .net application running on mono 4.0.1 in ubuntu.

The application is multi-threaded but the CPU usage not more than 25% on 4 core machine.

I think mono is just running on one of the cores and not using all the cpu cores on the server.

I ran the mono profiler, please find the truncated output

```
Monitor lock summary
        Lock object 0x7f0a621b6f58: 21 contentions
                0.000609 secs total wait time, 0.000049 max, 0.000029 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a703c9270: 14 contentions
                0.000311 secs total wait time, 0.000034 max, 0.000022 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a74b8cbc8: 1 contentions
                0.000023 secs total wait time, 0.000023 max, 0.000023 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a703cae90: 1 contentions
                0.000020 secs total wait time, 0.000020 max, 0.000020 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a7489c4b0: 1 contentions
                0.000017 secs total wait time, 0.000017 max, 0.000017 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a703d5c00: 1 contentions
                0.000017 secs total wait time, 0.000017 max, 0.000017 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a74afdf60: 1 contentions
                0.000012 secs total wait time, 0.000012 max, 0.000012 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a74b21d60: 1 contentions
                0.000010 secs total wait time, 0.000010 max, 0.000010 average
        Lock object 0x7f0a74b21ac8: 1 contentions
                0.000010 secs total wait time, 0.000010 max, 0.000010 average
        Lock contentions: 42
        Lock acquired: 42
        Lock failures: 0

Thread summary
        Thread: 0x7f0a711ff700, name: "Timer-Scheduler"
        Thread: 0x7f0a604ff700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7f0a635de700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7f0a63dfe700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7f0a63fff700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7f0a71786700, name: "Finalizer"
        Thread: 0x7f0a75ebb7c0, name: ""
        Thread: (nil), name: "Main"

Counters:
        Mono System:
                User Time                      : 0.000ms
                System Time                    : 20.000ms
                Total Time                     : 0.000ms
                Working Set                    : 9244672
                Private Bytes                  : 168361984
                Virtual Bytes                  : 214839296
                Page Faults                    : 2742
                CPU Load Average - 1min        : 0.020000
                CPU Load Average - 5min        : 0.050000
                CPU Load Average - 15min       : 0.050000
        Mono JIT:
                Methods from AOT               : 0
                Methods JITted using mono JIT  : 6
                Methods JITted using LLVM      : 0
                Total time spent JITting (sec) : 0.000597
```

How do I set up mono to use all the cores on the server ? This is the only process runnning on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score -4):

Make sure you are using SMP (Symmetric Multi Processing) in kernel. If you  dont  know how to do this use the google.

Comment: This is 2015, not 1999.